# Is the Ark of the Covenant symbolizing the cherubim guarding the Tree of Life?

Tags: judaism, eden, book-of-life, ark-of-the-covenant

No one questions why cherubim were used as symbolism throughout the OT.

Cherubim are involved with finding God. The Meaning of Life.

I think the role of cherubim is to guard things by hiding with illusion.

Comment: The sword guards the way to the tree of life. IT is preventing humanity from accessing the tree of Life. The cherubim do not guard. They await the dawn (the east) of a new humanity (in Christ) which shall fulfil God's desire in humanity. The cherubim are a concept. They are not real creatures. That concept is detached from Adam, it only appears when the first humanity fails. Then it waits. Your Q needs to ask about the sword, not cherubim. I recommend a free download of the book “The Cherubim of Glory” from this link. It has 187 pages of exposition. https://belmontpublications.co.uk/books/

Comment: Can you add the scripture references you are concerned with, and show some of your reasoning? That would help define the scope of your question, as cherubim, ark of the covenant, and tree of life all occur in multiple verses in different books.

Comment: @Robert  A huge number of related scriptures concerned with the Ark of the Covenant, the cherubim etc are carefully explained in the book I mention. With the best will in the world, I cannot condense 187 pages into a few hundred words!

Comment: @Robert  I'm not asking for any answers. There is a God has asked this Q, to which I only gave my comment. I've suggested a book on the subject which does give doctrinal answers. That's simply my comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Genesis 3:24 So he drove out the man; and he placed at the east of the
> garden of Eden **Cherubims**, and a **flaming sword** which turned
> every way, to keep **the way** of the tree of life.

Jesus is **The Way** to the Tree of Life.

"flaming sword" (God's Righteous Word) is The Way to the goal of our test, Life

> 2Ki 19:15 Then Hezekiah prayed before the LORD, and said: **“O LORD
> God of Israel, the One who dwells between the cherubim**, You are God,
> You alone, of all the kingdoms of the earth. You have made heaven and
> earth.
>
> 2Ch 5:8 For the cherubim spread their wings over the place of the ark,
> and the **cherubim overshadowed the ark** and its poles.
>
> Eze 10:3 Now the **cherubim** were standing on the south side of the
> temple when the man went in, and the cloud filled the inner court.
>
> Eze 41:18 And it was made with cherubims and palm trees, so that a
> palm tree was between a cherub and a cherub; and **every cherub had
> two faces**;

two faces? good and evil?​

> Eze 41:20 From the ground unto above the door were **cherubims** and
> palm trees made, and on the wall of the temple.

If the temple is inside us, is it saying we have good and evil?​

If satan was a "covering cherub" in Ezekiel 28:16 of the OT, could lucifer have been a top cherub guarding the Tree of Life? Did both his faces turn evil?

> Exo 25:22 “And there I will meet with you, and I will speak with you
> from above the mercy seat, from **between the two cherubim** which are
> on the ark of the Testimony, about everything which I will give you in
> commandment to the children of Israel.
>
> Num 7:89 Now when Moses went into the tabernacle of meeting to speak
> with Him, he heard the voice of One speaking to him from above the
> mercy seat that was on **the ark of the Testimony, from between the
> two cherubim**; thus He spoke to him.
>
> 1Sa 4:4 So the people sent to Shiloh, that they might bring from there
> **the ark of the covenant of the LORD of hosts, who dwells between the cherubim**. And the two sons of Eli, Hophni and Phinehas, were there
> with the ark of the covenant of God.

between the two cherubim ..where there isn't an illusion going on?​

> 1Ki 8:6 Then the priests brought in the ark of the covenant of the
> LORD to its place, into the inner sanctuary of the temple, to the Most
> Holy Place, **under the wings of the cherubim**.

—————————————

> Exo 26:31 “You shall make a **veil** woven of blue, purple, and
> scarlet thread, and fine woven linen. It shall be woven with an
> **artistic design of cherubim**.

The veil has symbols of cherubim?

cherubim **hide the Tree of Life** ..via the vail

> 2 Corinthians 3:15-16 But even unto this day, when Moses is read, the
> **vail** is upon their heart.
>
> 16 Nevertheless when it shall turn to the Lord, the **vail** shall be
> taken away.

satan **hides The Way** to the Tree of Life by blinding minds

> 2 Corinthians 4:4 In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds
> of them which believe not, lest the light of the glorious gospel of
> Christ, who is the image of God, should shine unto them.

Can satan deceive because he had the ability/free will as a cherub? Are there still good cherubim just doing their job, hiding the Tree of Life, without looking for worship?

Was the tempter a cherub? Do cherubim use death to hide life? Is it like a drug to them? Is death the Tree of Knowledge? Is this why they fell?
How many angels does it take to hide the Tree of Life? Are they not in a lake of fire right now because God is using them as a tool?

> Ezekiel 28:16-17 By the multitude of thy merchandise they have filled
> the midst of thee with violence, and thou hast sinned: therefore I
> will cast thee as profane out of the mountain of God: and I will
> destroy thee, **O covering cherub, from the midst of the stones of
> fire.**
>
> 17 Thine heart was lifted up because of thy beauty, thou hast
> corrupted thy wisdom by reason of thy brightness: I will cast thee to
> the ground, I will lay thee before kings, that they may behold thee.

O covering cherub, from the midst of the stones of fire.​

> Isaiah 14:12 (KJV) How art thou fallen from heaven, **O Lucifer, son
> of the morning!** how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst
> weaken the nations! via crossnote

O Lucifer, son of the morning!​

Are these combined saying lucifer was a covering cherub and "son of the morning!" has something to do with stones of fire?
Does "covering" mean he is hiding something ..like the Truth?

Does each town have it's own hierarchy of fallen angels (cherubim) causing carnal man to be unaware of the spiritual?

> 12 Then he said to me, "Do not be afraid, Daniel, for from the first
> day that you set your heart on understanding this and on humbling
> yourself before your God, your words were heard, and I have come in
> response to your words.
>
> 13 "But the prince of the kingdom of Persia was withstanding me for
> twenty-one days; then behold, Michael, one of the chief princes, came
> to help me, for I had been left there with the kings of Persia.
>
> —Daniel 10:12–13, NIV

I got the idea for some of the scripture from here https://biblereasons.com/spiritual-blindness/

and https://www.blueletterbible.org/

Answer (score 0):

Numbers 7:89
New International Version

> When Moses entered the tent of meeting to speak with the LORD, he heard the voice speaking to him from between the two **cherubim** above the atonement cover on the **ark of the covenant law**. In this way the LORD spoke to him.

The cherubim guarded the ark of the covenant law. The covenant law symbolized the tree of life. In this sense, the cherubim guarded the tree of life.

Is the Ark of the Covenant (including the cherubim above the cover) symbolizing the cherubim guarding the Tree of Life?

Yes.